# How to show the difference between two counts using aliases?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm creating custom views that show totals for different things in a database, and I'd like to also show the differences.

For example;

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents`) AS `doc_count`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`) AS `user_count`,
   (`doc_count` - `user_count`) AS `difference`;
```

I get an error using the aliases this way. Is there a way to write this query without repeating `select count(*)` queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap both queries with an additional query:

```
SELECT doc_count, user_count, doc_count - user_count AS difference
FROM   ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents`) AS doc_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`) AS user_count) t
```

Comment: ah, this won't work in a view but it does answer the question.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini it may work, when you fix opening and closing braces.

Comment: @AxelAmthor didn't notice the missing oppeners... grr. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use the aliases at same level of query you have to use the whole expression or use sub select

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents`) AS `doc_count`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`) AS `user_count`,
   ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents`) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`)) AS `difference`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "workaround" to get the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT C.doc_count
    ,C.user_count
    ,C.doc_count - C.user_count AS `difference`
FROM (SELECT
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents`) AS `doc_count`
         ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`) AS `user_count`) C
```

But i'm not sure about the performance of such kind of query...

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I would move these to the `from` clause and use `cross join`:

```
SELECT d.doc_count, u.user_count, (d.doc_count - u.user_count) as difference
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as doc_count FROM `documents`) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as user_count FROM `contacts`) u;
```

Comment: @MathewFoscarini . . . It seems simpler than two levels of nested queries.